# How do you copy paste on Xbox One?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, controllers, xbox-one

I wanna book ban my friend with The Bee Movie script but I can't copy or paste things on my controller. I use a controller because I am used to it and I'm pretty bad with keyboard and mouse controls. I personally do not have a keyboard and mouse for my Xbox and I am not willing to buy one just to copy and paste. Does anyone know how to copy and paste without buying a keyboard and mouse?

Comment: I know I've used the Xbox App on my Android phone to perform copy and paste operations with my Xbox.  But I don't know if that'll work within a game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Insider](https://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-copy-and-paste-on-xbox-one#:%7E:text=If%20you%20wish%20to%20highlight,%22%20or%20%22Select%20all.%22):

1. Launch the Microsoft Edge web browser, then place your cursor at the start of the text you want to copy by pressing the "A" button twice on your controller to highlight a specific word. If you wish to highlight more text, use your left joystick to highlight additional text.
2. After you have highlighted the text that you want to copy, press the "Menu" button on your controller (the one with three horizontal lines, beneath the Xbox button) and select "Copy" or "Select all

Comment: How do you paste it back in Minecraft or wherever you need it?

Comment: You'll have to press the menu button and click paste. The menu button is the button with three horizontal lines.